# C: Program crashes before completing for loop

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, io, crash

Hello Stackoverflow crew. I'm a very amateur C programmer and I'm working on a program that reads some input about wedding gifts, and then outputs information that includes the maximum gift value, the minimum gift value, the total average of the gift values, and the average of the gifts that were valued at x > 0. I've finished writing everything, but the program always seems to crash after the first loop. I've been looking at it for the past few hours, so I'm having issues finding what the error might be. Here is the code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {

    //Opens the file and creats a pointer for it.
    FILE *ifp;
    ifp = fopen("gifts.txt", "r");

    //Declares the variables
    int i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, x, y;
    int gift_sets, num_gifts, prices, max_value, max, avg_val, no_zero;

    //Scans the file and assigns the first line to variable "gift_sets"
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &gift_sets);

    //Begins a for loop that repeats based on the value of gift_sets
    for (i = 0; i < gift_sets; i++) {

        printf("Wedding Gifts #%d\n", i + 1);
        printf("Gift Value\t Number of Gifts\n");
        printf("----------\t ---------------\n");

        //Scans the price values into the array prices[num_gifts]
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &num_gifts);
        int prices[num_gifts];

        //Creates a loop through the prices array
        for (j = 0; j < num_gifts; j++){
            fscanf(ifp, "%d", &prices[j]);
        }

        //Declares a frequency array
        int freq[max + 1];

        for (k = 0; k <= max; k++) {
            freq[k] = 0;
        }

        for (l = 0; l < num_gifts; l++) {
            freq[prices[l]]++;
        }
        for (m = 0; m < max + 1; m++) {
            if (freq[m] > 0){
                printf("%d\t%d",m, freq[m]);
            }
        }

        printf("\n");

        //Zeroes the variable "max_val."
        int max_val = prices[0];

        //Loops through the array to find the maximum gift value.
        for (n = 0; n < num_gifts; n++){
            if (prices[n] > max_value)
                max_value = prices[n];
        }

        // Zeroes "min_val."
        int min_val = prices[0];

        //Finds the lowest value within the array.
        for(o = 0; o < num_gifts; o++){
            if(prices[o] !=0){
                if(prices[o] < min_val){
                    min_val = prices[o];
                 }
             }
        }

        //Calculates the total number of gifts.
        double sum_gifts = 0;
        for(p = 0; p < num_gifts; p++){
            sum_gifts = sum_gifts + prices[p];
        }

        //Calculates the average value of all the gifts.
        avg_val =  (sum_gifts / num_gifts);

        //find non zero average
        double x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        for(q = 0; q < num_gifts; q++){
            if (prices[q] != 0){
                x += prices[q];
                y++;
            }
        }

        //Calculates the average value of the gifts, excluding the gifts valued zero.
        int no_zero = x / y;

        //Prints the maximum gift value.
        printf("The maximum gift value is: $%d", max_value);
        printf("\n");

        //Prints the minimum gift value.
        printf("The minimum gift value is: $%d\n", min_val);


        //Prints the average of all the gifts.
        printf("The average of all gifts was $%.2lf\n",avg_val);

        //Prints the no zero average value of the gifts.
        printf("The average of all non-zero gifts was $%.2lf",no_zero);
        printf("\n\n\n");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help guys. As always, it's much appreciated.

EDIT: To further elaborate, the "crash" is a windows error "gifts.exe has stopped working" when executing the program. It does say at the bottom of the window that "Process returned -1073741819 <0xC0000005>"

Comment: It would help if you edited the question to include any error message(s) you get. Also, have you tried debugging using gdb or similar?

Comment: That's the thing, there are no error messages. The program builds and runs just fine, but I get a windows error "gifts.exe has stopped working" when executing the program. It does say at the bottom of the window that "Process returned -1073741819 <0xC0000005>"

Comment: that error code is an access violation, meaning you're probably trying to dereference a null pointer somewhere.

Comment: @lnafziger, has nobody here heard about VLAs? :-)\

Answer (score 3):

When you declare the array with the num_gifts variable, it generates assembly instructions which allocate enough space on the stack to hold num_gifts integers. It does this at compile-time. Normally this wouldn't compile, but depending on the behavior of the ms c compiler, it could compile and assume whatever value is put in num_gifts by default (maybe 0, maybe something else) is the length. When you access it, it's possible that you're trying to access an array with zero elements, which could cause an access violation.

Comment: The behavior of your code as it's currently written is what's called "undefined" in the parlance of the C standard. Just FYI if you want to read more about it.

Comment: I don't think that's correct - welcome to c99 and VLAs :-) If MSVC doesn't support them, it would have raised an error "non-constant expression in array dimension" or similar. If it does support them, that syntax is fine.

Comment: Actually, I haven't, lol!  Nice feature though!  However, since it is inside the for loop, won't it allocate the first time through the loop and then leave it alone for the following loops (leaving it at the original size?) (Similar to a "int x = 0" in a for loop?)

Answer (score 2):

I'll tell you one thing you *should* do, straight away.

Check the return values from `fscanf` and its brethren. If, for some reason the scan fails, this will return less than you expect (it returns the number of items successfully scanned).

In that case, your data file is not what your code expects.

You should also be checking whether `ifp` is NULL - that could be the cause here since you blindly use it regardless.

One thing you'll find in IDEs is that you may not be in the directory you think you're in (specifically the one where `gifts.txt` is).

And, on top of that, `max` ill be set to an arbitrary value, so that `int freq[max+1];` will give you an array of indeterminate size. If that size is less than the largest price, you'll be modifying memory *beyond* the end of the array with:

```
freq[prices[l]]++;
```

That's a definite no-no, "undefined behaviour" territory.

Answer (score 1):

At least at first glance, it looks like you haven't initialized `max` before you (try to) use it to define the `freq` array.